How can I handle multiple async requests in parallel with dynamic inputs in .NET Core?
I'm working on a .NET Core application where I need to make several asynchronous HTTP requests in parallel. The number of requests depends on dynamic user input (which could range from 5 to 50), and the results from these requests need to be processed once all of them are completed.
Here’s an example of how I’m currently handling the requests using Task.WhenAll, but I’m not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it:
var tasks = urls.Select(url => httpClient.GetStringAsync(url)).ToArray();
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Requirements:
The list of URLs is dynamically generated based on user input.
If any request fails, I still want the other requests to complete.
I need to handle a high volume of requests without overwhelming the system.
Bonus: Is there a way to limit the number of concurrent requests (e.g., 10 at a time)?
What’s the best approach to handle this in .NET Core for scalability and performance?
Should I use Task.WhenAll or is there a better pattern for handling dynamic and parallel tasks?

"in parallel" Note this is not parallel but concurrent. Asycnhronous operation are generally done sequentially (i.e. using 1 core). Using multiple cores can often help to get better performance assuming you are not IO bound. IDK if this is possible in .Net (probably).

"limit the number of concurrent requests" AFAIK, you can just do a for loop starting all the request up to 10. Then, beyond, you can wait any task and start another one. When there is no new task to start, you can wait all of them.
